# Output one signal to osciloscope using NI USB 6008

Tags: python

I want to send a sinus signal to an osciloscope using NI USB 6008 and I have some configuration problems ,can anyone help me!!
Somebody told me that i should use "OnDemand" clock timing,but i don't now exactly how.

Thanks a lot for the help!

The compiler give me two errors:

"DAQmxCfgImplicitTiming

### nidaq call failed with error -200077: 'Requested value is not a supported value for this property. The property value may be invalid because it conflicts with another property.'

"DAQmxWriteAnalogF64
nidaq call failed with error -200077: 'Requested value is not a supported value for this property. The property value may be invalid because it conflicts with another property.'

Comment: Please post the code that generates the error.

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem , the problem was that the device I've used was not capable for hardware timing, so I've found a new solution to use a software timing.Thanks